# Grails application - Unable to restrict AJAX access from same domain by specifying different domain via "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" response header

Tags: grails, http-headers, cross-domain, access-control

I am basically trying to setup Cross origin request control on this Grails project. 
Right now, I am trying to test the negative case by making the change for a single API end point. Here is the change I have added to my controller file, which is a .groovy file -

```
response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://somedomain.com')
        response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, PATCH')
        response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Additional-Headers-Example')
        response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
        response.setHeader('Access-Control-Max-Age', '1728000')
```

And here is what I am getting in the response of the AJAX call made to this end point from a browser -

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Additional-Headers-Example
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, PATCH
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://somedomain.com
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date: Fri, 14 Jun 2019 14:56:41 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=95
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) mod_jk/1.2.42 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

As per my understanding, a different domain appearing in the respponse header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is enough to fail a call. But this is not happening. My application is running on localhost port 8080.

Doubting that this could be because there is no domain attached to my localhost, I deployed the code on a server which has a valid domain name, http://someotherdomain.com. But, there as well, I see this negative test case not passing. Any pointers?

**Update**

If relevant, the initiator value against one such request is jquery.min.js file which is executing from http://someotherdomain.com.

[image]